# Manifest JSON file returning 404 not found error along with a syntax error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have read the other posts on this matter and have tried to use the answers provided and none of them worked. I am hoping that someone can help me with this issue. I am building an application using React and AWS Lambdas. I do not have a public folder to place the manifest file into. I have placed the file in the templates folder that stores my html files as well as the root of the project and I am still receiving the error that it cannot be found. I am also not sure why it is complaining about my syntax. I ran it through JSONLint just to make sure that it was indeed valid and no errors were returned. Below is my manifest.json file:

```
    {
    "short_name": "bat",
    "name": "bat",
    "description": "bat",
    "icons": [{
            "src": "/images/image.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/image.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "/?source=pwa",
    "background_color": "#3367D6",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "theme_color": "#3367D6",
    "shortcuts": [{
            "name": "bat",
            "short_name": "bat",
            "description": "bat",
            "url": "./?source=pwa",
            "icons": [{
                "src": "/images/image.png",
                "sizes": "192x192"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "bat",
            "short_name": "bat",
            "description": "bat espanol",
            "url": "./es?source=pwa",
            "icons": [{
                "src": "/images/image.png",
                "sizes": "192x192"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

If there is anything else you might need please let me know.

***Update***
I am still having issues with my project seeing that there is a manifest.json file. The React application was not built using create-react-app. It was built from scratch. I have been brought in to help maintain and add new features. One of these new features is the manifest.json file to convert the website to a PWA. Therefore I have added the `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />` to both of my html files as there are only two html files in the whole project. I have also created the manifest.json file in the root directory per this [article](https://web.dev/add-manifest/) and still no luck with the manifest.json file being read properly as I still receive the 404 (not found) error as well as the Line 1, column 1 Syntax Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding the manifest file in /public is not sufficient.

You will also have to add manifest in the index.html head tag.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="public/manifest.json" />
```

Try this out.

Comment: Also make sure that icons path are correct in manifest.

Comment: I have tried that as well. I don't have an index.html file. The way this project is setup there are only two html files and I have added the `<link rel="manifest href="/manifest.json" /> to both files and I still receive the 404 error.

Comment: So it turns out this was the answer. I needed to do a few more configurations for the project but this ended up being the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the entire path in the `href` manifest :

`<link rel="manifest" href="your_template_folder/manifest.json" />`

Also I didnt have a public folder, but I use manifest .json in another folder for the PWA stuffs and using it this way works.